# My conversion from Matic to Dock resulted in lost funds

Tags: 0x

I attempted a conversion of matic to dock transaction hash id is 0xea1abb0ac3fc257966bd5331cee6dbffd9d6a5a25a909392480a7b889e6613b9 Yet 99% of all my funds vanished

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Our team is looking into what happened with your transaction, and we will get back to you as soon as we know more.

Edit: After reviewing this transaction, it seems that this was not a case of bad order routing. The 0x API did in fact surface the only available liquidity for the `buyToken`. There is very little DEX liquidity for the DOCK token, so you made a legitimate trade on a highly illiquid asset.